# Lengths of review process of mathematical journals

Tags: publications, journals, peer-review

Do you have any file containing the information of peer-review process lengths of mathematical journals?If yes, It will be very helpful for me.
Thanks for your helps.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The AMS maintains a list of the backlogs of research journals, which should give you some indication.

The most recent one (I think) can be found here: http://www.ams.org/notices/201310/rnoti-p1390.pdf